# Dynamic include with twig using Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, twig

I'm using `node.js` with `twig` as template engine and I need to add some html when a button is clicked, I tried to add the include  using javascript on the frontend this way

```
$('#add-question').on('click',function(){
        $('#questions-container').append("{% include './create-question.twig'  %}");    
})
```

But append the literall text, Its possible to include a twig template inside another this way or similar?

Comment: just add this html as usual, and make them don't visible by display:none. Then just on click action change displaying to block or what you need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)